# SPFolder.Files.Add creates the file but does return null

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm uploading files to a document library in SharePoint 2010 by using the Add method of a SPFolder.Files object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472956.aspx). This worked fine, until someone made a template out of an existing library (where this is still working) and created a new library out of the template.

On this new libary the Add call still finishes without exception but does return an SPFile object with Items property == null.

In the SharePoint UI the file does not show in the library, but when I connect to the library via Microsoft Explorer it's there.

I have the impression that the file is created but no item is created. Does anyone know this problem? Are there solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem and a solution (more or less):

This happens only, if versioning was activated in the library the template was created from. It happens in libraries that are created from this template.

To solve it, **I had to deactivate the versioning in the new library and activate it again**. After this all missing files appeared and the Add method works fine, again.

*Does anybody know if this is a known bug in 2010 and if there is a hotfix?*

EDIT: Answer yes, this was a known bug and it was **fixed in the december 2010 cumulative update** (I rechecked with cu feb 2011 and couldn't reproduce it anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to checkin and or publish the file after calling Add, if versioning is enabled.  (SPFile.CheckIn)

Comment: Nope, already tried that. I checked it without the code, too. Even FormServices itself doesn't save the file right, until versioning ist turned off and on again. Seems to be a SP2010 bug.